# how to Handle Empty Model Validation in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a simple action using ASP NET Core (Not old web api or mvc):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<SomeResponse> Something([FromBody] SomeRequest request)
{
    // request is null here when the POST body is empty
}
```

When I POST an empty body `request` is null. I have a global action filter that returns a generic 400 response if there are any model validation errors.

```
public class ValidateModelBindingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // 400 response here.
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the ModelState to be invalid if the body is empty so that the validation filter will respond with a 400 before attempting to execute the action with a null request object. I tried adding a `[Required]` attribute to the `request` parameter to no effect. Is there another solution out there?

Comment: can you post the request class code ?

Answer (score 2):

it considers `Null` model valid because it checks `ModelState.ErrorCount` in case of `null` it will be `0` thats why it will consider it as valid model so you can try this

```
 public class ValidateViewModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
            {
                if (actionContext.ActionArguments.Any(x => x.Value == null))
                {
                    actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

                }

                if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
                {
                    actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
        }
```

and dont forget to add the `ValidateViewModel` attribute on `action`

Comment: This works, but it's not exactly the solution I was hoping for. I don't want to apply a non-null constraint to all actions. I also want the ability to say one particular parameter in an action may not be null but another parameter can be.